# Error message in NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

Can anyone help me to understand what I should add here to make sure no error message is shown?

the code is:

```
NSolve[(2*Pi*1.4 )/lambda1  == 
    k1 2 Pi && (2 Pi *1.4)/lambda2  == (k1 + 1) 2 Pi, {lambda1, lambda2}] /.k1 -> 554
```

And I got error message:

```
Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
```

Strangely, if I simply change the 1.4 in the numerator to 1, there will be no error message. The code with no error:

```
sol1 = NSolve[(2*Pi*1)/lambda1  == 
 k1 2 Pi && (2 Pi *1)/lambda2  == (k1 + 1) 2 Pi, {lambda1, 
lambda2}] /. k1 -> 554
```

Comment: `1.4` is an approximate real (floating point) number; `1` is an exact (integer) number. `Solve` works on exact numbers and converts approximate ones to exact with `Rationalize[]`.  The message is just a warning.  `NSolve` probably calls `Solve` because your solutions depend on a parameter `l1`, and `NSolve` is not meant for such equations.

Comment: My `l1` is actually defined. Even if I delete `l1` it still shows the message.

Comment: modified code like this `NSolve[(2*Pi*1.4)/lambda1 == 
    k1 2 Pi && (2 Pi*1.4)/lambda2 == (k1 + 1) 2 Pi, {lambda1, 
   lambda2}] /. k1 -> 554`

Comment: I tried to Rationalize` the `1.4` and it worked, but I still don't get the logic of it.  The code that have now error is: `NSolve[(2*Pi*Rationalize@1.4)/lambda1 == 
    k1 2 Pi && (2 Pi*Rationalize@1.4)/
     lambda2 == (k1 + 1) 2 Pi, {lambda1, lambda2}] /. k1 -> 554`

Comment: You're substituting the value of the parameter ***after*** `NSolve` has solved the system (and given the warning in the first case).

Comment: BTW, it's a warning, not an error, and you can ignore it if you're satisfied with the result.

Comment: Oh yes, if I do not use the substitution and so it does not call the `Solve` I don't have the `Warning` (`error`) message anymore.